# How to get the derivative of the 2-norm of a vector with respect to a matrix？

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to get the derivative of the 2-norm of a vector with respect to a matrix？
For
$$
f(\textbf{X})=\|\textbf{aX}\|^2_2,
$$
it is easy to obtain
$$
\frac{\text{d}f}{d\textbf{X}}=\textbf{a}^T\textbf{a}^*\textbf{X}^*.
$$
where $\textbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{l\times l}$, $\textbf{a}\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times a}$.

But for
$$
f(\textbf{X})=\|\textbf{aX}\|_2,
$$
how to get the derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite simple.
Let $f(\mathbf{X})=g^2(\mathbf{X})$

Using differential, you will find

$$ df = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{X}} : d\mathbf{X} =
2 g(\mathbf{X}) dg
$$
Here : denotes the Frobenius inner product.

It follows
$$
dg
=\frac{1}{2 g(\mathbf{X})} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{X}} : d\mathbf{X}
$$
The gradient is thus
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
=\frac{1}{2 g(\mathbf{X})} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your reply!

Comment: you are welcome. I have updated my answer since an error was present.